# Pascal User input into Array

Tags: arrays, input, printing, pascal

How do I create an Array of 3 numbers
A: Array [1..3] of integer

Now , how do I make an user to input 3 numbers, into Array A ?
And print them out like
Array A= ( number 1, number 2, number 3) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Once you've made an effort to do your own work and run into difficulties, we'll be more than happy to help; you can just explain the problem you've run across, include the *relevant portions* of the code you've written, and ask a specific question, and we'll do our best to help. If you can't get started on your assignment, ask your instructor for help. Good luck.

Comment: If i wanted you to do my homework, i would write down the specifications). I want to learn, but i can't find an example . Do i need to write a for loop like in Java ?

Answer (score -2):

```
USES
  WinCrt;
CONST
  n = 3; ---> Number of "numbers" in Array
VAR
 i : INTEGER;
 A, B, C, D : ARRAY [1..n] OF INTEGER;

FOR i := 1 TO n DO  {Input into  A}     -> Condition that makes you input 3 times the "number"
    BEGIN
      WRITE('A[', i, '] --> ');
      READLN(A[i]);              -> Listens keyboard for user input
    END;
```

Do same for the rest of the Arrays..

That is it, u didn't have to help
It's pretty selfish when you have the knowledge how to to code/ do something, and than you don't want to share it.Or to purpose an idea how to do it.

Comment: Which Pascal compiler?  The syntax of your variable declarations is wrong; please do not post code that does not compile in an answer.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, which compiler?

Comment: Turbo Pascal 7.0

Comment: Then the declaration of `i` ought to be `var i: integer`  Similar for `A` and `B`.  And `CONS` should be `CONST`.

Comment: @Learner4491: **No, it doesn't work for you**. The code you posted is not valid in any version of Pascal I know, and certainly not in Turbo Pascal 7. You did not post the real, compiling code, you just typed in something that looks a bit like it. That is not a good answer.

Comment: Oh my god. When you need help no one wants to help out. When your done here are the comments.

Comment: USES
  WinCrt;
CONST
  n = 3;  VAR
 i : INTEGER;
 A, B, C, D : ARRAY [1..n] OF INTEGER;FOR i := 1 TO n DO  {input to array  A}
    BEGIN
      WRITE('A[', i, '] --> ');
      READLN(A[i]);